# More Than One OG URL Specified and only Yoast graph is open not Jetpack

Tags: wordpress, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, yoast

I'm having some problem with the od: tags which is the most common issue.

[image]

Only Yoast is active for open graphs not Jackpack publicize and then how the og: tags are showing in the header of the page as shown above in the image.
would be grateful if anyone can help

Answer (score 0):

There can be two possibilities:

1. The other og tag is printed in theme's header.php. If it's there then comment that code and you're good to go.
2. The OG tag is being generated by some function hooked to `wp_head` hook. Now it can be anywhere, in any file in plugin or theme. The best approach would be to check all the hooked functions for `wp_head` hook. You can do so by this code:

   add_action("wp", function(){ print_r($GLOBALS['wp_filter']); echo '';exit; } );

Write this code in functions.php of your theme and look for all the functions which are hooked with `wp_head` hook. You can then comment the code in that particular function.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your template adds the additional og:url header (from your page source it appears so). You need to disable the additional headers using either a switch in template settings or by manual edit.